# Ckeditor searching for assets in root URI, while it's application is on sub URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I've spent the past two days trying to fix this bug, but I really don't have anymore ideas or tools to solve it. I wonder if anyone here in stackoverflow can help me.

I'm trying to fix a website source code that uses the ckeditor gem. The ckeditor gem deliver a embedded web text editor. The problem is that the gem does not do it's job when the website is placed on a subdirectory. If the website is placed in the root directory like www.domain.com it works perfectly, but when I place it at a subdirectory, like www.domain.com/website, it does not show up the text editor.

The cause of not showing the editor is that the application try to find the assets of the ckeditor gem at the root directory of the server:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/skins/kama/editor.css?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/lang/pt-br.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/plugins/embed/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/plugins/attachment/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
```

When the right adress would be www.domain.com/**website**/assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=C3HA5RM

I've really searched over all the web trying to find the solution for this, but the only few similar situations that I found didn't provided me a solution.

In this [Issue](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/126), at github, the user jronallo has the exactly same problem than me. But I tried to implement his solution but was not successful.
In this commit, at the ckeditor repository, the bug seems to be fixed, but even having this fix on my gem, (ckeditor 4.0.2 and rails 3.2.2) it keeps missing the assets on SubUri.

I've also tried manipulating the CKEDITOR_BASEPATH and the Ckeditor.relative_url, manually, but not succesfull again.

Does anyone have any idea about how can solve it? I would appreciate very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete in your ckeditor config external plugins.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/plugins/embed/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://domain.com/assets/ckeditor/plugins/attachment/plugin.js?t=C3HA5RM
And it's works!

My config:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2003-2011, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
*/

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    config.language = I18n.locale;
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // Rails CSRF token
  config.filebrowserParams = function(){
    var csrf_token = jQuery('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        csrf_param = jQuery('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
        params = new Object();

    if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
      params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
    }

    return params;
  };

  config.addQueryString = function (url, params) {
    var queryString = [];

    if (!params)
      return url;
    else {
      for (var i in params)
        queryString.push(i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[ i ]));
    }

    return url + ( ( url.indexOf("?") != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join("&");
  };

  // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
  CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    var content, upload;

    if ($.inArray(dialogName, ['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash']) > -1) {
      content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
      upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

      if (upload && upload.filebrowser['params'] == null) {
        upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
        upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
      }
    }
  });

  /* Extra plugins */
  // works only with en, ru, uk locales
//  config.extraPlugins = "embed,attachment";

    //for orfografii
  config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
//  config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';


  /* Toolbars */
  config.toolbar = 'Mini';
  config.toolbar_Mini =
    [
        ['Source','-','Preview'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
//        ['Styles','Format'],
      ['Subscript', 'Superscript'],
//      ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'TextColor'],
//        ['Maximize','-','About'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline'], ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote']//,
//        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
//        ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'], ['Image', 'Attachment', 'Flash', 'Embed'],
//        ['Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak']
    ];

  config.toolbar = 'VeryEasy';
  config.toolbar_VeryEasy =
    [
        ['Source','-','Preview'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
//        ['Styles','Format'],
      ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'TextColor'],
        ['Maximize','-','About'],
        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'], ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
//        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
//        ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'], ['Image', 'Attachment', 'Flash', 'Embed'],
        ['Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak']
    ];

  config.toolbar = 'Easy';
  config.toolbar_Easy =
      [
        ['Source', '-', 'Preview'],
        ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
        ['Styles', 'Format'],
        ['Subscript', 'Superscript', 'TextColor'],
        ['Maximize', '-', 'About'],
        '/',
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike'],
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote'],
        ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
        ['Image', 'Attachment', 'Flash', 'Embed'],
        ['Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak']
      ];
  config.jqueryOverrideVal = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with ckeditor searching for skins on *root dir* because i was loading ckeditor.js dinamically after the whole page load.

The solution I've found in [this thread](http://ckeditor.com/comment/125441#comment-125441)
was to set the global var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH before the call to ckeditor.js.